# Grab Value from Cell as a Format

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, type-conversion

I am using VBA to pull in a bunch of data from several workbooks into several worksheets and then process that data later.
WorkFlow: As I pull the data into my workbook, I first place all my data into arrays before outputting them into my worksheets.

### Problem

While I am pulling in data, I noticed that some of the "Hours" or "Work Order Number" data are pulled into my arrays in the form of dates or datetime, when they should just be some number format. 
`e.g.:`
`I should be getting: 
   Number of Hours: 2; Work Order Number: 41235612`
`Instead, I am getting: 
   Number of Hours: 0-Jan-00 (equivalent to 1/0/1900, which was originally entered as "0")
   Work Order Number: 0-Jan-00`
I found that the issue lies in the source documents, where it looks like Excel may have automatically (although incorrectly) converted those cell values into a date type form, when first entered as a plain number.

### Question

- How can I pull data from the different documents into my arrays so
  that all values in that column come out as what they should be (a
  Number)?

  - Is there a way to format the value before placing it into the array?

    - Can I format the value into a number format like the "General" number format (or something that makes sense) while it is being pulled?

I would rather not make any changes within the source documents, and just format the values I am pulling as I pull them.

Comment: the `Range.Formula` property, vs. `Range.Value` I assume you are using now, will return the underlying numeric value of a cell, for a constant. Alternatively, if you know it should be a number regardless of cell number format but the previous method is not appropriate as some values may be spat out by a formula, you can iterate the relevant elements of your array and convert them to a number using e.g. `CDbl(ele)`.

Comment: Have you tried using (eg) `CLng()` ?

Comment: How did you `Dim` your array variables?

Comment: Array is variant.
it is not the array's datatype's fault. it is the fault of the values being extracted since the source document is where the fault is being extracted from.

Comment: have not used CLng... can I get an explanation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Range().value2` instead of `.value` property

the `.value2` dont accept Currency and Date formats, so it should read your hours values properly.

for example cell A1 has value 2 and saved with Date format.

so `Range("A1").value` will return date value "1/2/1900"

`Range("A1").value2` will return numeric value 2 you can save in your array.

---

You can format the values with `Clng()` or `CDbl()`.
for example:

```
CDbl(Range("A1").Value)
```

But if the cell  has non numeric value, for example text, code throws an error!

---

And you can format the cells (source or destination) with `.NumberFormat` property

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "General"
```

Comment: I assume both Clng() and Cdbl() will behave similarly (error throwing)?
Any thoughts comparing the 3 different courses of action?

Comment: Found it best (in my case) to either use value2 or to pre-format the source document before data extraction. Causes least amount of headaches for me.

Comment: yes, Clng Cdbl throws errors in case of wrong arguments type.
I preffer myself the .value2 way. Fast and simple.
Pre/Post -formatting slows performance, use it only if .value2 cant help.